# git add repositories into subdirectory preserving history

Tags: git, composer-php, git-merge, git-subtree

I have to add one git repository into a subfolder into another repository preserving history of both repositories (merge a composer package repository into the main repository to require with type 'path'). The goal is to have just one repository with all project specific packages in one repository at the end.

I tried the subtree workflow, but with the merge command

```
git merge -s ours --no-commit repo/branch
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

How can I manage this?

Thank you for your answers!

Sebastian

Answer (score 1):

From git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---allow-unrelated-histories).

> **--allow-unrelated-histories**
>
> By default, git merge command refuses to merge histories that do not
> share a common ancestor. This option can be used to override this
> safety when merging histories of two projects that started their lives
> independently. As that is a very rare occasion, no configuration
> variable to enable this by default exists and will not be added.

Use `--allow-unrelated-histories` to merge two unrelated histories with `git merge` command.